# "Mind my/your own business" german translation

Tags: word-choice

I'm new here. 
Today i wanna ask you how do the people say "Mind my/your own business" or "I've got to mind my own business", or "I've got [something] to mind on" in german?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where have you looked and what have you found so far?

Answer (score 3):

Some translations for the "mind your own business". (from less impolite to impolite)

> Kümmere dich um deine eigenen Angelegenheiten!
>
> Kümmere dich um deinen eigenen Kram!
>
> Kümmere dich um deinen eigenen Dreck!

Other related sentences (which are more "That is none of your business") are;

> Das geht dich nichts an!
>
> Das geht dich einen Schmarren an!

But be careful, these sentences can be very offensive and rude.

Comment: *Das geht dich nichts/einen Schmarrn/... an* has a slightly different meaning.

Comment: (adding to tofro's comment) It means "That's none of your business" and in a pretty familiar/crude/direct way (as opposed to "That doesn't concern you").

Answer (score 2):

I like

> Keine Einmischsache!
>   *(No matter to meddle!)*

as an alternative to

> Halt dich da raus!
>   *(Keep out (of the matter)!)*

The first one is a special choice (from a girl on the street), the second one is common.

Comment: Never heard this one. Is it regional or from a book/movie?

Comment: @Marzipanherz: Please see my updated answer.

Comment: from a girl on the street :) +1

Comment: Never heard of "Keine Einmischsache". In fact, "Einmischsache" has only one Google hit, which isn't even about the whole word...

Comment: @Pollitzer Nice creation and *interesting* source :)